# How to modify bits in EC of a laptop on BSD?

Tags: freebsd, bsd, openbsd

I am a new user trying to make BSD as my daily driver. Apparently, the only thing stopping me is unable to control the fan. I am using Gigabyte Aero 10th Gen Intel Core i7 with NVIDIA GTX 1660Ti card. It has pre-defined fan curve settings like normal, gaming, quiet etc. I need to turn on a profile based on what I am working on, e.g., I set it to gaming when I am compiling code or rendering video. But I set it to normal other times, as it sounds like a jet engine. I was surprised when everything is working fine out of the box except the fan. Currently, I am using Fedora where I control fans through writing bits on EC using [c program](https://github.com/jertel/p37-ec) uses ec_sys of Linux.

My laptop gets pretty hot but, I don't want to set any limit on the CPU frequency. I came to the conclusion that my laptop's fans cannot be controlled through ACPI (or I am not capable of). Furthermore, I explored and tried all possible solutions, such as Arch's documentation or any other code regarding fan control. I tried to create an account in the forum but neither Gmail nor ProtonMail is working during registration, I don't know what is wrong! Thank you for the time and consideration.

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253745/discussion-on-question-by-stackoverflow-user-how-to-modify-bits-in-ec-of-a-lapto).

Answer (score 1):

BSD family doesn't implement an `ACPI` sensor framework, so for the fan control, unlike with Linux which provides `lm-sensors` Some server's motherboard implement `IPMI`, which has driver and tools on FreeBSD, but I doubt you can use it with the system you described here. You will get more information here on the `Unix SE`: [freebsd-kernel-module-to-control-fan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393417/freebsd-kernel-module-to-control-fan-speed), you will find many ways to access the cooling system, and you can gather some infos through `dmidecode -t 27` (SMBIOS spec. type 27 : Cooling Device). Programmatically on FreeBSD, accessing and modifying kernel state is done through `sys/sysctl.h` API, and using `sysctl` call with a `mib_vector` type array. If you want some help on this, plz provide a more accurate question.

Comment: `sysctl` is an utility (or an API ...) that allows you to modify kernel states, ie, kernel specific and kernel modules states, so, while you load the right kernel mod which publishes some of its states, yes. But as I said before, BSD systems do not provide sensor module (required by Embedded Controller like FAN speed).